# HUD is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I need to load some images from a JSON Object. When these images are loading, I need to show a HUD on my view. I tried to define a HUD like following,

**Define HUD in viewDidLoad method**

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading Images";
[hud show:YES];
[hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadJSONData) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

**loadJSONData method**

```
-(void)loadJSONData{
   _myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

   id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
   NSArray *dataDic = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"data"];
   for (NSDictionary *dicData in dataDic) {
      Lawyer *l = [[Lawyer alloc] init];
      dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl",l.imageUrl];
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           l.uiImage = image;
        });

     });
   [_myObject addObject:[l initFromDictionary:dicData]];
   }
}
```

My out put is showing the HUD for a second and disappeared. No data is loading. How do I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD), much much easier to use the MBProgressHUD..

Comment: set a minimum display time. It's likely the loadJSONData is running very quickly

Comment: After I do that, Images are shows, when I'm scrolling it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView: self.view];
[self.view addSubview: hud];
hud.labelText = @"Loading Images...";

[hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    [self loadJSONData];
} completionBlock:^{
    // Refresh UI 
}];
```

But make sure , as `whileExecutingBlock` using thread you have to make all UI change on main thread.

Comment: Sorry for that i just copy my code from Xcode and put there .You've to add your method name there.

Comment: It's also, no data is loading. Loads only empty table.

Comment: what you add to completionBlock ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58148/discussion-between-user3452995-and-ibhavin).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. `loadJSONData` performs an asynchronous request so the selector has actually finished executing. What you should do is show the HUD before the method `loadJSONData` and then hide it when the data has been received in:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   l.uiImage = image;
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
```

Although personally I would have a callback in `loadJSONData` and perform the HUD dismissal in a completion block.